# How to search partition schema, filegroup and text image at once in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, extended-properties

The following query was performed.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_PARTITION_SCHEMA] 
(
    [COL] [INT], 
    [COL2] [INT]
) ON [PartitionSchema] ([COL])
GO

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
    @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'partition_schema_comment', 
    @level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo', 
    @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=N'TB_PARTITION_SCHEMA'
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_FILEGROUP] 
(
    [COL] [INT], 
    [COL2] [VARCHAR](max)
) ON [test1fg]
TEXTIMAGE_ON [test2fg]
GO

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
    @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'filegroup comment', 
    @level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo', 
    @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=N'TB_FILEGROUP'
GO
```

I want to search the partition schema, filegroup, text image, and table comments all at once.

Please advise.

---

**Detailed Question**

- A partition schema (partition column) is specified for table A.
- A filegroup is assigned to table B.
- A text image is assigned to table C.

And I want to lookup tables A, B, and C all at once for schema. (Each table is commented.)

As a result of my testing, if table B with a filegroup specified is searched, table A cannot be searched due to conditions.

Also, text images cannot be viewed.

Obviously I'm looking it up wrong, but I need help with this.

Comment: "And I want to lookup tables A, B, and C all at once for schema" what exactly about these tables do you want to look up?

Comment: Perhaps you want something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=16e8d651403defd7fae398d8034ce4d8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the catalog view `sys.extended_properties`

```sql
select *
from sys.extended_properties ep
where ep.name = 'MS_Description';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=852dd8148f974d83cff91f74acaa4ec6)

Comment: I know how to look up comments.
I've edited the question for a more detailed question. please check

Comment: I don't understand what you are now asking. "if table B with a filegroup specified is searched, table A cannot be searched due to conditions" what does that mean? What are you trying to do that you cannot? What is a "text image"?

Comment: Maybe it's a JOIN problem. First of all, apart from
The text image seems to be the lob_data_space_id of the table.
In this regard, you can check the generated query at the link below, and we will update the post to include more details about the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. Extended properties can't be images. Are you perhaps asking about the `TEXTIMAGE_ON` option in the `CREATE TABLE` statement? It's really really unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: Could it be okay if I delete all the content of the question and then re-write it?

Comment: Possibly, it's generally not appreciated to change the question entirely after someone has posted an answer. Best just post a new question, and revert the changes to this one.

Comment: A new question has been registered. Please confirm.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73609922/how-to-inquire-partition-schema-filegroup-etc-in-sqlserver