# How to inquire partition schema, filegroup, etc. in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server

This is a similar question to the one I posted earlier, but with changes.

I created a table like this:

### Table with partition schema applied

```sql
CREATE TABLE TB_PARTITION_SCHEMA (
    COL INT,
    COL2 INT
)
    ON PartitionSchema (COL)
GO;

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
    @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Partition Schema Comment', 
    @level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo', 
    @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=N'TB_PARTITION_SCHEMA'
GO
```

### Table with filegroup applied

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_ONLYFG] (
    [COL] [INT]
)
    ON [test2fg]
GO

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
    @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Only FileGroup', 
    @level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo', 
    @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=N'TB_ONLYFG'
GO
```

### Table with text image applied

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_TEXTIMAGE] (
    [COL] [VARCHAR](max)
)
    TEXTIMAGE_ON [test1fg]
GO

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
    @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Only TextImage', 
    @level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo', 
    @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=N'TB_TEXTIMAGE'
GO
```

### Table with filegroup and text image applied

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_FILEGROUP] (
    [COL] [INT],
    [COL2] [VARCHAR](max) 
)
    ON [test1fg]
    TEXTIMAGE_ON [test2fg]
GO

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
    @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'fileGroup, TextImage Comment', 
    @level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo', 
    @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=N'TB_FILEGROUP'
GO
```

I want to search these tables at once.
The query I've tried is:

```sql
SELECT
        t.name as tableName
    ,   f.name as fileGroupName
    ,   f.log_filegroup_id 
    ,   t.lob_data_space_id 
    ,   CAST(ep.value AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS comment
FROM sys.indexes as i
INNER JOIN sys.tables as t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.filegroups f ON i.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties ep ON ep.class = 1
AND ep.minor_id = 0
AND t.object_id = ep.major_id
AND ep.name = N'MS_Description'
WHERE t.schema_id = 1
ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

| tableName | fileGroupName | logFileGroupId | lob_data_space_id | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TB_FILEGROUP | test1fg | NULL | 3 | fileGroup, TextImage Comment |
| TB_ONLYFG | test2fg | NULL | 0 | Only FileGroup |
| TB_TEXTIMAGE | PRIMARY | NULL | 2 | Only TextImage |

The question is:

1. There is no way to query the partition schema and partition columns in the current query.
   What is it?
2. How to search data specified as text image?

For both questions, I want the partition schema for each table and the partition column to be verifiable as a column as shown in the table above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that although partition schemes are data spaces, they are not a filegroup, so you won't find them in `sys.filegroups`. Instead you need to join `sys.data_spaces`.

You should also filter `sys.indexes` to only the heap or clustered index, otherwise you could get multiple rows per table.

It's unclear what you mean by `fileGroup` in the `comments` column, I presume you mean to check whether it's the default filegroup.

`lob_data_space_id` on the `sys.tables` view will tell you if `TEXT_IMAGE` is being used.

The extended properties can be aggregated in a subquery using `STRING_AGG`.

```sql
select
  tableName = t.name,
  d.type_desc space_type,
  fileGroupName = d.name,
  t.lob_data_space_id,
  comment = CONCAT_WS(',
',
      CASE WHEN d.is_default = 0 THEN d.type_desc END,
      CASE WHEN t.lob_data_space_id > 0 THEN 'TEXT_IMAGE' END,
      ep.props
    )
from sys.tables t
join sys.indexes i on i.object_id = t.object_id and i.index_id in (0,1)
join sys.data_spaces d on d.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
left join sys.data_spaces td on td.data_space_id = t.lob_data_space_id
outer apply (
    select string_agg(cast(ep.value as nvarchar(4000)), '
')
    from sys.extended_properties ep
    where ep.major_id = t.object_id
      and ep.name = 'MS_Description'
) ep(props);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=87694ff4c4b995cb99203e47648172af)

Comment: The logFileGroupId attribute is a column in the sys.filegroup table, and I thought I could query the attribute called text image.

But contrary to my intention, it consists only of numbers whose meaning is unknown.
As you answered, I want to know the text image information, just like the partition schema name and file group name for each table.

Comment: Documentation says "Identified for informational purposes only. Not supported. Future compatibility is not guaranteed. In SQL Server, the value is NULL.". Is there anything my query doesn't do for you?

Comment: understanding goes.

Where can I find out what the purpose of information provision is? Is it possible to attach a link such as a url?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Ignore `logFileGroupId` forget you ever saw it

Comment: It seems that communication is difficult because I am not used to English.

What I'm wondering is "Identified for informational purposes only. Not supported. Future compatibility is not guaranteed. In SQL Server, the value is NULL.". I would like to know the source of the official document material containing the content.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-filegroups-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16